# Como criar uma list com alguns atributos em java?

Tags: java

Estou com problemas para criar uma list onde eu possa inserir diferentes valores.

Utilizo os seguintes códigos:

```
public class avaliacaoMensal {
    private String questao;
    private char potencial;
    private int resultado;
}

public avaliacaoMensal todosMensal(){    
    List<avaliacaoMensal> dados = new ArrayList<avaliacaoMensal>();
    dados.add("Aaa", 'a', 1);    
}
```

Como fazer isso funcionar?

```
public AvaliacaoMensal todosMensal(){
        List<AvaliacaoMensal> dados = new ArrayList<AvaliacaoMensal>();
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Aaa", 'a', 1));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Bbb", 'b', 2));
        dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Ccc", 'c', 3));
        // Continuação do código

        return (AvaliacaoMensal) dados;
    }
```

Ai quando eu adicionar, gera o erro

AvaliacaoMensal() in AvaliacaoMensal cannot be applied to: Expected Parameters: Actual Arguments

Comment: A dúvida é: como iniciar o objeto diretamente no método `add` da lista?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Renan

Comment: @LucasCharles Eu coloquei no final da minha resposta como você pode fazer isso.

Comment: @jbueno Muito obrigado, está me salvando. Mas está dando o seguinte erro: AvaliacaoMensal() in AvaliacaoMensal cannot be applied to:
Expected Parameters:
Actual Arguments:

Comment: Preciso ver o código pra saber do que você tá falando

Comment: @jbueno Editei la

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60019/discussion-between-lucas-charles-and-jbueno).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não faz muito sentido. Um `ArrayList` de `avaliacaoMensal` só pode conter objetos do tipo `avaliacaoMensal`. Você precisa criar uma instância desta classe e adicionar o elemento na lista.

```
public avaliacaoMensal todosMensal(){
    List<avaliacaoMensal> dados = new ArrayList<avaliacaoMensal>();
    avaliacaoMensal aMensal = new avaliacaoMensal();
    // Fazer algo para setar o valor dos atributos questao, potencial e resultado
    dados.add(aMensal);
}
```

Perceba que o código atual da classe `avaliacaoMensal` não contém os métodos de acessos às propriedades da mesma (os famosos `getters` e `setters`), você precisa criá-los.

Também é bom seguir o padrão de nomenclatura do Java para nomes de classes (camel case com a primeira letra maiúscula), a classe deveria se chamar `AvaliacaoMensal`.

Uma prática bastante comum também é  a criação de construtores que recebam como parâmetro alguns valores de atributos, para já criar uma instância da classe com alguns valores determinados.

Sua classe, seguindo estas dicas, ficaria assim:

```
public class AvaliacaoMensal {
    private String questao;
    private char potencial;
    private int resultado;

    public AvaliacaoMensal(String questao, char potencial, int resultado) {
        this.questao = questao;
        this.potencial = potencial;
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }

    public String getQuestao() {
        return questao;
    }

    public void setQuestao(String questao) {
        this.questao = questao;
    }

    public char getPotencial() {
        return potencial;
    }

    public void setPotencial(char potencial) {
        this.potencial = potencial;
    }

    public int getResultado() {
        return resultado;
    }

    public void setResultado(int resultado) {
        this.resultado = resultado;
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira, você poderia usar parecido com o que tentou no início:

```
public AvaliacaoMensal todosMensal(){    
    List<AvaliacaoMensal> dados = new ArrayList<AvaliacaoMensal>();
    dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("Aaa", 'a', 1));
    // Continuação do código
}
```

[Você pode ver funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso210733)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer da seguinte forma.

AvaliacaoMensal.java vai ter esse código:

```
public class AvaliacaoMensal {
private String questao;
private char potencial;
private int resultado;

public String getQuestao() {
    return questao;
}

public void setQuestao(String questao) {
    this.questao = questao;
}

public char getPotencial() {
    return potencial;
}

public void setPotencial(char potencial) {
    this.potencial = potencial;
}

public int getResultado() {
    return resultado;
}

public void setResultado(int resultado) {
    this.resultado = resultado;
}

}
```

---

Agora você pode pegar uma classe de teste e fazer isso para ver se funciona :

```
    ArrayList<AvaliacaoMensal> lista = new ArrayList<AvaliacaoMensal>();

    AvaliacaoMensal avaliacao = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        avaliacao = new AvaliacaoMensal();
        avaliacao.setPotencial('T');
        avaliacao.setQuestao("Teste");
        avaliacao.setResultado(2);
        lista.add(avaliacao);
    }
```